# List of files that should ne be allowed to be served by apache

Tags: security, web

My Apache web server should never serve a directory named ".git" or a file named "*.sqlite", or "config.php". It's so much probably a mistake that the potential false positive is worth it.

I guess relying on apache rules is not the best security practice, but as a second line of defense, is there a list of such files and folder names I should never serve?

I have this for now, with a global scope:

```
<DirectoryMatch "/\.git">
   Require all denied
</DirectoryMatch>
<FilesMatch ".*[.]sqlite|config.php">
   Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I'd suggest keeping your sensitive files out of the web root.

Comment: Thanks @Panki, as said this is a second line of defense. I manage servers where others people also put their websites. public_html etc.